# How to use ng-class within a dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I not familiar with ng-class in AngularJS, I need to know how can I disabled a selectlist in AngularJS when an option has been chosen and enable it when no option has been chosen.If An object is empty enable the selectlist and if and object is not empty disabled the selectlist. This is what I tried but it doesn't work

HTML

```
<select class="categories" ng-class="{'disabled':Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId !== 0}"  ng-model="Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId" ng-options="downtimeCategory.CategoryId as downtimeCategory.CategoryName for downtimeCategory in Model.DowntimeCategories">
</select>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

 .controller('DowntimeController', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.Model = new Model($http);
     $scope.Model.CurrentDowntime = {};   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`disabled` is a property, not a class. Use [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled):

```
<select class="categories"
        ng-disabled="Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId !== undefined"
        ng-model="Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId"
        ng-options="downtimeCategory.CategoryId as downtimeCategory.CategoryName for downtimeCategory in Model.DowntimeCategories">
</select>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still the selectlist is not disabled when there is a selected value

Comment: Sorry, I got the syntax wrong. Remove the {{ }} braces from the `ng-disabled` directive